# Why am I getting a "Cannot Get /" error message in express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just started learning back-end development so this may be a very simple mistake. I got an error "Cannot Get /" after entering localhost:3000 into my browser. Here is my index.js file and a router module. They are both in the same folder, 'basic-node-site':

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const path = require('path')

router.get("/", function (req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'))
})

router.get("/contact-me", function (req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/contact-me.html'))
})

router.get("/about", function (req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/about.html'))
})

module.exports = router
```

```
const router = require('./route-module.js')
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.use(express.static('basic-node-site'))

app.use("/route-module", router)



app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("listening on port 3000")
})
```

I tried multiple different pathnames just in case I was misunderstanding something about how they were formatted. Every time I got "cannot get /" where I expected to get the HTML file displayed in the browser.

Comment: What is your expected output? Your server routes are only in `/route-module`, and for the public dir you need an index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

The path is not accurate in index.js file, can you change

```
app.use("/route-module", router)
```

into below

```
app.use("/", router)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't go to the **public** folder. The `index.html` file and other html files are in **public** folder right?

You should do this:

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'))
});

router.get("/contact-me", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/contact-me.html'))
});

router.get("/about", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/about.html'))
});
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: "the index.html file and other html files are in public folder right" — Wrong. The question clearly states **They are both in the same folder, 'basic-node-site':**

Comment: Oh right. sorry, I just read another comment. you don't have a route for `/`
you have just `/route-module` , `/route-module/contact-me`, and `/route-module/about`
If you want to create another route for that you need to do this.
`app.use("/", rootRoute)`
and then create another file like `route-module.js` for rootRoute.
to get `index.html` try this in your browser **http://localhost:3000/route-module**